# Dynamic Loader Issue on AIX with JNA

Tags: java, jna, aix

When executing my application via the Java interface on AIX, the JNA code is generating a dynamic loader error, which is never retrieved or flushed from the error buffer. This is in turn interfering with the dynamic load operations due to its mere presence. To work around this issue, we flushed the error buffer before starting the dynamic load operations. Using the work around we are able to successfully execute the application.

The JNA dynamic loader error is the following: "The system call does not exist on this system. (Java_com_sun_jna_Native_write)".

Has anyone seen this type of error and did you find a solution?

Thanks,
Doug